# Writing a binding to libpcap with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, libpcap

I've been banging away at this for a while an I'm unsure of the issue here. For some reason my device is being changed and I'm unsure why. I suspect it has to do with how I'm mapping the libpcap libs to ctypes because the same program written in pure C works just fine on my host. The code is as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.2

import ctypes,sys
from ctypes.util import find_library


#pcap = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libpcap.so")
pcap = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(find_library("libpcap"))

# required so we can access bpf_program->bf_insns
"""
struct bpf_program {
    u_int bf_len;
    struct bpf_insn *bf_insns;}
"""
class bpf_program(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("bf_len", ctypes.c_int),("bf_insns", ctypes.c_void_p)]

class sockaddr(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_=[("sa_family",ctypes.c_uint16),("sa_data",ctypes.c_char*14)]

class pcap_pkthdr(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("tv_sec", ctypes.c_long), ("tv_usec", ctypes.c_long), ("caplen", ctypes.c_uint), ("len", ctypes.c_uint)]

pcap_lookupdev = pcap.pcap_lookupdev
pcap_lookupdev.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
#pcap_lookupnet(dev, &net, &mask, errbuf)
pcap_lookupnet = pcap.pcap_lookupnet
#pcap_t *pcap_open_live(const char *device, int snaplen,int promisc, int to_ms, char *errbuf)
pcap_open_live = pcap.pcap_open_live
pcap_open_live.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
#int pcap_compile(pcap_t *p, struct bpf_program *fp,const char *str, int optimize, bpf_u_int32 netmask)
pcap_compile = pcap.pcap_compile
#int pcap_setfilter(pcap_t *p, struct bpf_program *fp)
pcap_setfilter = pcap.pcap_setfilter
#const u_char *pcap_next(pcap_t *p, struct pcap_pkthdr *h)
pcap_next = pcap.pcap_next

# prepare args
snaplen = ctypes.c_int(1540)
linktype = ctypes.c_int(12) # DLT_RAW on linux
program = bpf_program()
#buf = ctypes.c_char_p(filter)
optimize = ctypes.c_int(0)
mask = ctypes.c_int(0)

errbuf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(256)

dev = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf)
dev = bytes(str('en1'), 'ascii')

if(dev):
    print("{0} is the default interface".format(dev))
else:
    print("Was not able to find default interface {0}".format(errbuf.value))



mask = ctypes.c_uint(32)
net = ctypes.c_uint(32)

if(pcap_lookupnet(dev,ctypes.pointer(net),ctypes.pointer(mask),errbuf) == -1):
    print("Error could not get netmask for device {0}".format(errbuf.value))
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    print("Got Required netmask")



to_ms = ctypes.c_int(1000)
promisc = ctypes.c_int(1)
handle = pcap_open_live(dev,snaplen,promisc,to_ms,errbuf)

if(handle is False):
    print("Error unable to open session : {0}".format(errbuf.value))
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    print("Pcap open live worked!")


filter = bytes(str('port 80'), 'ascii')
buf = ctypes.c_char_p(filter)


if(pcap_compile(handle,ctypes.byref(program),buf,ctypes.c_int(1),mask) == -1):
    # this requires we call pcap_geterr() to get the error
    print("Error could not compile bpf filter because {0}".format(errbuf.value))
else:
    print("Filter Compiled!")


if(pcap_setfilter(handle,ctypes.byref(program) == -1)):
    print("Error couldn't install filter {0}".format(errbuf.value))
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    print("Filter installed!")


header = pcap_pkthdr()
if(pcap_next(handle,ctypes.bref(header)) == -1):
    print("ERROR pcap_next failed!")

print("Got {0} bytes of data".format(pcap_pkthdr().len))
pcap_close = pcap.pcap_close
pcap_close(handle)
```

For some reason when we get to pcap_compile() the system tries to look up one of the vmware interfaces instead of the value assigned to dev  .. here is the output.

```
bash-3.2# ./libpcap.py 
b'en1' is the default interface
Got Required netmask
Pcap open live worked!
Error could not compile bpf filter because b'vmnet8: No such device exists (BIOCSETIF    failed: Device not configured)'
Bus error: 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
if(handle is False):
```

A NULL pointer returned from `ctypes` is `None`.  In Python it is customary to just say:

```
if not handle:
```

I suspect handle is invalid because `dev` is not in the correct format.  Note in Python parentheses are not required with `if`.

As an aside:

```
bytes(str('string'), 'ascii')
```

can simply be:

```
b'string'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(find_library("pcap"))
```

On my ubuntu 16.04, `find_library` failed unless the name was given without the 'lib' prefix.